# add services to init.d on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, service, init.d

I'm trying to simplify commands on my ubuntu server.

For now, to start / stop / restart apache2, we have to type those commands :
stop : `/etc/apache2/bin/apachectl -k stop`
start : `/etc/apache2/bin/apachectl -f /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`
restart : `/etc/apache2/bin/apachectl restart`
and kinda same for MySql :
stop : `mysqladmin -u root shutdown`
start : `mysqld_safe --user=mysql --log &`

What I wish is to be able to use `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` or `/etc/init.d/mysql start` to make it simple and not having to always look at the Wiki to find the exact command to use each time...
I tried to find samples of files to put in `init.d` folder, but found nothing.

I also wanted to know how to do the same with `service apache2 start` (and same for stop/restart and MySql).
Is there a difference between using `/etc/init.d/xx start` and `service xx start` ?
Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the executable file i.e `apachectl` in `/etc/init.d/` and than try with `/etc/init.d/apache{tab} restart/start/stop` and all for mysql too it will work.

Actually `init.d` contains the shell script file that is executable.

Take care the file should be executable like below 
    `chmod +x /etc/init.d/apachectl`

Comment: Ok, isn't there any script to write in order to say `start` means : running the executable with `-f /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` parameter ?

Comment: yes if you properly configured environment variable than. just try out by placing /bin/apachectl to /init.d/

Comment: and one more thing if you install apache in ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install apache` than it would be by default installed in /init.d/ directory no need to do this long process I think

Comment: We had to install MySql and Apache manually since we need specific versions to be production-like. I can actually use /etc/init.d/apache2 restart/start/stop (after renaming apachectl), it works. What do you mean by "yes if you properly configured environment variable" ? what should I put in my environnement variables ?

Comment: Means you have to make your default `/bin` in path like `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` you will find that by `vim ~/.profile` if its /bin than it will execute all the shell script and in your case it will be so you can place shell file inside /init.d/ and execute it.